# R: Changing Duplicate Values Within Subjects

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements

```
 Subj  Trial  Time
1 A      1     250
2 A      2     250
3 A      3     280
4 B      1     250
5 B      2     270
6 B      3     290
```

Above is an example of the data I am working with. I have different subjects (*Subj*) performing the same set of trials (*Trial*). Unfortunately, when trial event happen in rapid succession, my equipment will print the same time values (***see Time column for rows 1 and 2***).


I cannot have the same subject have duplicate time values, HOWEVER, it is okay for different subjects to have the same time values. Thus, I need a way to conditionally change duplicates such that ONLY time duplicates within a particular subject are changed. 


Ideally, I'd like to change the above example to something like below:

```
 Subj  Trial  Time
1 A      1     250
2 A      2     250.5
3 A      3     280
4 B      1     250
5 B      2     270
6 B      3     290
```

Any recommendations on how I might be able to accomplish this?


Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`. We can group the data by `Subj` and `Time`, count the number of occurrences, and then change the `Time` by adding `0.5` if number of occurrences is more than 1.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(Subj, Time) %>%
  mutate(Count = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Time = ifelse(Count > 1, Time + 0.5, Time)) %>%
  select(-Count)
dt2
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#    Subj Trial  Time
#   <chr> <int> <dbl>
# 1     A     1 250.0
# 2     A     2 250.5
# 3     A     3 280.0
# 4     B     1 250.0
# 5     B     2 270.0
# 6     B     3 290.0
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = " Subj  Trial  Time
1 A      1     250
2 A      2     250
3 A      3     280
4 B      1     250
5 B      2     270
6 B      3     290",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution works perfectly!! Although, I had a little bit of trouble getting it to work at first...... I hadn't attached my dataframe, and instead just called the columns via dt$Subj or dt$Time. This caused me to get an "unexpected =" error at the second mutate. After I attached the dataframe, and called the columns alone (as you are showing in your example), it worked!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat similar to the already provided solution, but without counting. This is comprised of two solutions:

`base R`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, list(df$Subj, df$Time)), function(x) {
    x$Time <- x$Time + seq(0, by=0.5, length.out=nrow(x))
    x
}))
```

`tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)


df %>%
    group_by(Subj, Time) %>%
    mutate(Time2 = Time + seq(0, by=0.5, length.out=n()))
```

They should both yield something similar to the following:

```
#  Subj Trial Time 
#  A    1     250.0
#  A    2     250.5
#  B    1     250.0
#  B    2     270.0
#  A    3     280.0
#  B    3     290.0
```

The key is to split your dataframe into chunks defined by the combination of the columns of `Subj` and `Time`. From here, the remaining is easy: you increment the values in the `Time` column by `0.5` starting with `0`, with the length of such a sequence being the same as that of the chunk.

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: This solution works great as well! Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base R` option with `duplicated`.  We create a logical index of duplicate elements based on the columns 'Subj', 'Time' and then assign the 'Time' value for those elements by adding 0.5 to it.

```
i1 <- duplicated(df1[c('Subj', 'Time')])
df1$Time[i1] <- df1$Time[i1] + 0.5
df1
#  Subj Trial  Time
#1    A     1 250.0
#2    A     2 250.5
#3    A     3 280.0
#4    B     1 250.0
#5    B     2 270.0
#6    B     3 290.0
```